# Using higher-order components in TypeScript to omit React property on usage

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a higher-order component in TypeScript which takes some React component class, wraps it, and returns a type that has one of the declared properties omitted.  This is what I've tried:

```
interface MyProps {
  hello: string;
  world: number;
}

interface MyState { }

function HocThatMagicallyProvidesProperty<P, S, T extends {new(...args:any[]): React.Component<Exclude<P, "world">, S>}>(constructor: T): T {
  throw new Error('test');
}

const MyComponent = HocThatMagicallyProvidesProperty(class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  constructor(props: MyProps, context: any) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  public render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
})

function usingThatComponent() {
  return (
    <MyComponent
      hello="test"
    />
  );
}
```

However, when using the component I get the error:

> Type '{ hello: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>...'.
>     Type '{ hello: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
>       Property 'world' is missing in type '{ hello: string; }'.

I've also tried this HOC declaration:

```
function HocThatMagicallyProvidesProperty<P, S, T extends {new(...args:any[]): React.Component<P, S>}>(constructor: T): {new(...args:any[]): React.Component<Exclude<P, "world">, S>} {
  throw new Error('test');
}
```

However, this neither works at the usage of the class, nor on the actual HOC invocation.

How can I define a higher-order component such that the `world` property doesn't have to be passed in at the usage of the class?

Comment: There is no recognition in the type system of class decorator mutation.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've updated the question to ask about how to do it with higher-order components instead, as that should cause the type system to recognise the mutated class.

Comment: Yeah, that is the correct way, but I don't think you are using `Exclude<T, U>` correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of some folks on the TypeScript Gitter, we ended up with this solution:

```
import { Dissoc } from 'subtractiontype.ts';

export interface ValidationProps {
  onValidationStateChange: (valid: boolean) => void;
}

type OuterProps<P> = Dissoc<P, keyof ValidationProps>;

export function IsValidatableComponent<P extends ValidationProps>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<P>): React.ComponentType<OuterProps<P>> {
  // ...
}

// usage:

export const RulesetFieldEditor = IsValidatableComponent(class RulesetFieldEditor extends ... {
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler version that allows wrapping of both class and function components.
A bit explicit naming for readability (hopefully)

```
// OLD VERSION:
// export type TPropOmit <T, K extends string> = (
//   Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
// )
// END OF CHANGE

// NEW VERSION: 2018-08-25
export type TPropOmit <T, K extends string> = (
  T extends any
    ? Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
    : never
)
// END OF CHANGE

export namespace withSomePropsSet {
  export type TPropsInject = {
    world :number
  }
}
export function withSomePropsSet <
  TPropsOrig extends withSomePropsSet.TPropsInject,
  TPropsNew = TPropOmit<TPropsOrig, keyof withSomePropsSet.TPropsInject>
> (
  WrappedComponent :React.ComponentType<TPropsOrig>
) :React.ComponentType<TPropsNew>
{
  const injectProps :withSomePropsSet.TPropsInject = {
    world: 123,
  }
  return (props :TPropsNew) :React.ReactElement<TPropsOrig> => (
    <WrappedComponent {...injectProps} {...props} />
  )
}
```

And usage:

```
type TMyProps = {
  hello ?:string
  world  :number
}
class MyCompCls extends React.Component<TMyProps, {}> {
  public render () {
    return (<div>{this.props.hello} {this.props.world}</div>)
  }
}
const MyCompFn = (props :TMyProps) => {
  return (<div>{props.hello} {props.world}</div>)
}

const MyCompClsWrapped = withSomePropsSet(MyCompCls)
const MyCompFnWrapped  = withSomePropsSet(MyCompFn)

const UsagePreWrap = (<>
  <MyCompCls                                 /> {/* INVALID */}
  <MyCompCls  hello = 'test'                 /> {/* INVALID */}
  <MyCompCls  world = {123}                  /> {/* OK */}
  <MyCompCls  hello = 'test'  world = {123}  /> {/* OK */}

  <MyCompFn                                 /> {/* INVALID */}
  <MyCompFn  hello = 'test'                 /> {/* INVALID */}
  <MyCompFn  world = {123}                  /> {/* OK */}
  <MyCompFn  hello = 'test'  world = {123}  /> {/* OK */}
</>)

const UsagePostWrap = (<>
  <MyCompClsWrapped                                /> {/* OK*/}
  <MyCompClsWrapped hello = 'test'                 /> {/* OK */}
  <MyCompClsWrapped world = {123}                  /> {/* INVALID */}
  <MyCompClsWrapped hello = 'test'  world = {123}  /> {/* INVALID */}

  <MyCompFnWrapped                                   /> {/* OK */}
  <MyCompFnWrapped    hello = 'test'                 /> {/* OK */}
  <MyCompFnWrapped    world = {123}                  /> {/* INVALID */}
  <MyCompFnWrapped    hello = 'test'  world = {123}  /> {/* INVALID */}
</>)
```

#### UPDATE

- **2018-08-25**:

  > Updated the 'TPropOmit' utility type to better handle union types
  >   thanks to comment by '[vilic](https://github.com/vilic)' on the following github issue:
  >   https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types/issues/19

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `Exclude` correctly, exclude will exclude the second type parameter from the first, so `Exclude<'a'|'b', 'b'> == 'a'` You can use `Exclude`, `keyof` and `Pick` to omit properties from a type : `Pick<TProps, Exclude<keyof TProps, 'world'>>>`

The second part of the problem is that the type arguments for your function call are not what you might expect, hovering in VS code we see on the call to the HOC the following :

```
function HocThatMagicallyProvidesProperty<{}, {}, typeof MyComponent>(constructor: typeof MyComponent): typeof MyComponent
```

So `P` and `S` get inferred to the most generic type possible `{}`, and T remains `typeof MyComponent` and thus the retuned class will require the same props (and this would happen even if we were to correct the usage of `Exclude`)

A different approach, that works would be to use conditional types to extract `S` and `P`, and to construct the new constructor signature excluding the properties we don't want

```
type Props<T extends React.Component<any, any>> = T extends React.Component<infer P, any> ? P : never; 
type State<T extends React.Component<any, any>> = T extends React.Component<any, infer S> ? S : never;
function HocThatMagicallyProvidesProperty<T extends {new(...args:any[]): React.Component<any, any>}, 
    TProps = Props<InstanceType<T>>, 
    TState=State<InstanceType<T>>, 
    TNewProps = Pick<TProps, Exclude<keyof TProps, 'world'>>>(constructor: T) : 
(p: TNewProps) => React.Component<TNewProps, TState>  {
  throw "";

}

interface MyProps {
  hello: string;
  world: number;
}

interface MyState { }

const MyComponent = HocThatMagicallyProvidesProperty(class extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  constructor(props: MyProps, context: any) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  public render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
})

function usingThatComponent() {
  return (
    <MyComponent
      hello="test"
    />
  );
}
```