# Type Inference in Higher order Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a HoC in React that simply passes an extra property called name:

```
export interface WithNameProps {
  name: string;
}
function withName<P extends {}>(Wrapped: React.ComponentType<P & WithNameProps>): React.FC<P> {
    const WithName: React.FC<P> = (props) => <Wrapped {...props} name="typescript" />
    return WithName;
}
```

However, when I use it with a component:

```
const Person: React.FC<{age: number, name: string}> = ({name, age}) => <p>Name: {name}. Age: {age}</p>

const Me = withName(Person);

<Me age={10} />
```

I get the following error:

```
Property 'name' is missing in type '{ age: number; }' but required in type '{ age: number; name: string; }'
```

Typescript is not able to infer that `P` here is `{age: number, name: string}` without `WithNameProps` i.e. `{age: number}`.

It works if I explicitly pass the type as in here:

```
const Me = withName<{age: number}>(Person);
```

It also works if the I declare the props of Person as an intersection type:

```
const Person: React.FC<{age: number} & {name: string}> = ({name, age}) => <p>Name: {name}. Age: {age}</p>
```

Here, Typescript is probably able to destructure the type and infer it.

Can I modify this in a way such that I don't have to explicitly state the type or pass the intersection type?

I have Typescript playground link here (along with a simpler example): [Click here](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#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-VLkhrrc52PO9aFlFqHb9QBmXFPZmK6zQADWOnETBYUBRPZdzvUmgt2Vkg4NI6guImTQtBAeZRDmEDaD2UTYlGkgNkgvhWNet4Ig+JTWqaaj4LBMAwCgUD4KeCqvPArDhihrBPvONpwu+iKHkChqjgBLLAUgoHgZB0EULB4B5r4pHQHezCsGh1EENhuH4aeQA)

Comment: In your playground, there is no error for `<Me age={10} />`. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using higher-order components in TypeScript to omit React property on usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49717438/996081)

Comment: @KarolMajewski There is error for `<ErrorMe age={10} />`. It incorrectly expects `{name: string}` as an argument.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Thank you. It looks like a TypeScript bug to me.

Comment: @KarolMajewski I think so too. Typescript has structural types, so it shouldn't matter if we have a regular type or intersection type.

Comment: @AbdulsattarMohammed I opened an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39565. I have a feeling it has something to do with interfaces being open-ended, but it's best to see what the TypeScript team has to say.